# How can I avoid duplicates in ScriptDb?

Tags: database, google-apps-script, javascript-objects

I have some objects to save in the database, but they must be unique every time the script is executed. These objects are just going to change values every instance of the application. The  problem is that when I create the first object, more copies are also created every time the script is executed after that. I try to use the same object again, but when I do the query, I get objects from previous executions giving me the wrong values. I just want to be able to reset the same objects to their default values and not have many unnecessary copies in the ScriptDb.

Here is some code:

```
// Get a database instance
var database = getDb();

// Create a new employee instance
var myEmployee = {
element: "currentEmployee",
firstName: "",
lastName: "",
ID: 0,
manager: "",
managerEmail: "",
department: "1 - University Store",
startDate: "",
endDate: "",
regularHours: 0,
vacationHours: 0,
sickHours: 0,
personalHours: 0,
H2Hours: 0,
overtimeHours: 0,
totalHours: 0,
rowLocation: 0,
salaryType: "H",
};

var week1 = {
// Identify the week and for query purposes 
element: "Week1",

// User entries
HW: {THUR: 0, FRI: 0, SAT: 0, SUN: 0, MON: 0, TUES: 0, WED: 0},
VH: {THUR: 0, FRI: 0, SAT: 0, SUN: 0, MON: 0, TUES: 0, WED: 0},
SH: {THUR: 0, FRI: 0, SAT: 0, SUN: 0, MON: 0, TUES: 0, WED: 0},
PH: {THUR: 0, FRI: 0, SAT: 0, SUN: 0, MON: 0, TUES: 0, WED: 0},
TH: {THUR: 0, FRI: 0, SAT: 0, SUN: 0, MON: 0, TUES: 0, WED: 0},

// Calculated totals
TotalHW:0, TotalVH: 0, TotalSH: 0, TotalPH: 0, TotalHours: 0,

// Week totals
Vacation: 0, Sick: 0, Personal: 0, H2: 0, OT: 0, Regular: 0,
}

var week2 = {
// Identify the week and for query purposes 
element: "Week2",

// User entries
HW: {THUR: 0, FRI: 0, SAT: 0, SUN: 0, MON: 0, TUES: 0, WED: 0},
VH: {THUR: 0, FRI: 0, SAT: 0, SUN: 0, MON: 0, TUES: 0, WED: 0},
SH: {THUR: 0, FRI: 0, SAT: 0, SUN: 0, MON: 0, TUES: 0, WED: 0},
PH: {THUR: 0, FRI: 0, SAT: 0, SUN: 0, MON: 0, TUES: 0, WED: 0},
TH: {THUR: 0, FRI: 0, SAT: 0, SUN: 0, MON: 0, TUES: 0, WED: 0},

// Calculated totals
TotalHW:0, TotalVH: 0, TotalSH: 0, TotalPH: 0, TotalHours: 0,

// Week totals
Vacation: 0, Sick: 0, Personal: 0, H2: 0, OT: 0, Regular: 0,
}

// Save these to the database
database.save(myEmployee);
database.save(week1);
database.save(week2);
```

Then, I would use the statement `ScriptDb.getMyDb.query({element: element}).next()` to retrieve the object. The string element containing "currentEmployee", "Week1", or "Week2".

Comment: Could you show the code you're using?

Comment: Code added. Take a lot and hopefully you could help me.

Comment: Still no totally clear on how you are trying to edit the elements from the DB. If you want to edit something in the db, you have to retrieve it first, then make your changes and re-save it.

Comment: I know I have to do that. However, once I save the elements to the database, they are created over and over again. There are more elements every the I run the script. I don't want more. I just want to override the ones I previously saved.

Comment: If this is what you want to do then you will have to call `var obj = db.query({element: elemName}).next()` then make your edits to `obj`by doing whatever you have to, and finish it off with `db.save(obj)`. Don't redefine a new object and save that to the database, because that will create a new item in the database.

Comment: Ok so I should wipe out the database, create the objects once and then just set all the properties to their defaults every time I run it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid re-creating *uniquely-keyed* objects in ScriptDb, you must first check whether the object you're thinking of saving is already there. If it is, then you need to get the handle of the stored object to use for updates. If it's not there, you will `save()` your new object, and the return value will be the handle of the copy in the database.

The general pattern is this:

```
// Get a database instance
var db = getDb();

var result = db.query( {key:keyval, ...} );
if (result.hasNext()) {
  // The object already exists in ScriptDb
  var obj = result.next()
}
else {
  // The object doesn't exist in ScriptDb, so create it
  // This example would start by creating only the key values,
  // expanding the object during the update stage below.
  // Alternatively, you could create the entire object with all
  // its properties.
  obj = db.save({key:keyval, ...})
}

// Can now update the obj that is in ScriptDb
obj.prop1 = value1;
obj.prop2 = value2;
...

// Save updated object
db.save(obj);
```

Here's an example of how that pattern could apply to your code. You'll see here that the alternative approach to creating new objects is being used, in which the new object is created in ScriptDb with all its properties at once.

```
// Get a database instance
var database = getDb();

// Find or create employee instance
var result = database.query({element: "currentEmployee"});
if (result.hasNext()) {
  var myEmployee = result.next();
} else {
  myEmployee = database.save({
    element: "currentEmployee",
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    ID: 0,
    manager: "",
    managerEmail: "",
    department: "1 - University Store",
    startDate: "",
    endDate: "",
    regularHours: 0,
    vacationHours: 0,
    sickHours: 0,
    personalHours: 0,
    H2Hours: 0,
    overtimeHours: 0,
    totalHours: 0,
    rowLocation: 0,
    salaryType: "H"
  });
};

// Find or create Week1 instance
result = database.query({element: "Week1"});
if (result.hasNext()) {
  var week1 = result.next();
} else {
  week1 = database.save({
    // Identify the week and for query purposes 
    element: "Week1",

    // User entries
    HW: {THUR: 0,FRI: 0,SAT: 0,SUN: 0,MON: 0,TUES: 0,WED: 0},
    VH: {THUR: 0,FRI: 0,SAT: 0,SUN: 0,MON: 0,TUES: 0,WED: 0},
    SH: {THUR: 0,FRI: 0,SAT: 0,SUN: 0,MON: 0,TUES: 0,WED: 0},
    PH: {THUR: 0,FRI: 0,SAT: 0,SUN: 0,MON: 0,TUES: 0,WED: 0},
    TH: {THUR: 0,FRI: 0,SAT: 0,SUN: 0,MON: 0,TUES: 0,WED: 0},

    // Calculated totals
    TotalHW: 0, TotalVH: 0, TotalSH: 0, TotalPH: 0, TotalHours: 0,

    // Week totals
    Vacation: 0, Sick: 0, Personal: 0, H2: 0, OT: 0, Regular: 0,
  });
}

// Find or create Week2 instance
result = database.query({element: "Week2"});
if (result.hasNext()) {
  var week2 = result.next();
} else {
  week2 = database.save({
    // Identify the week and for query purposes 
    element: "Week2",

    // User entries
    HW: {THUR: 0,FRI: 0,SAT: 0,SUN: 0,MON: 0,TUES: 0,WED: 0},
    VH: {THUR: 0,FRI: 0,SAT: 0,SUN: 0,MON: 0,TUES: 0,WED: 0},
    SH: {THUR: 0,FRI: 0,SAT: 0,SUN: 0,MON: 0,TUES: 0,WED: 0},
    PH: {THUR: 0,FRI: 0,SAT: 0,SUN: 0,MON: 0,TUES: 0,WED: 0},
    TH: {THUR: 0,FRI: 0,SAT: 0,SUN: 0,MON: 0,TUES: 0,WED: 0},

    // Calculated totals
    TotalHW: 0, TotalVH: 0, TotalSH: 0, TotalPH: 0, TotalHours: 0,

    // Week totals
    Vacation: 0, Sick: 0, Personal: 0, H2: 0, OT: 0, Regular: 0,
  });
}

// At this point, myEmployee, week1 and week2 refer to the ScriptDb objects.
// While we can use them as any javascript object, they also contain information
// relevant to their state as ScriptDb objects.
...
```